# Compute custom function nth row using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dplyr

Given the following data frame:

```
A   B        C       D
1   92.44   14261   13183
2   92.43   14244   13166
3   94.24   14730   13882
4   97.42   12149   11836
5   94.75   14431   13674
6   95.91   11038   10587
7   95.66   14886   14240
8   94.94   12587   11950
9   94.27   13251   12492
10  94.89   12789   12135
```

I am trying to using R create `rowwise` computation that allows me to `summarize()` the first **4** rows in columns C and D, divide them accordingly and replace it with the next row.

```
replace(nth row + 1) = SUM(C) / SUM(D)
```

Here is what I have tried

```
df %>% mutate(B=replace(mpB, nrow(4)=summarise(C/D), NA))
```

Desired Output

```
A   B        C      D
1   92.44   14261   13183
2   92.43   14244   13166
3   94.24   14730   13882
4   97.42   12149   11836
5   94.01   14431   13674
6   95.91   11038   10587
7   95.66   14886   14240
8   94.94   12587   11950
9   94.27   13251   12492
10  95.18   12789   12135
```

*Update the 5th row and 10th row with desired calculation

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what output you're trying to achieve, but maybe this is a start; `df %>% 
  mutate(group4 = (1:n() - 1) %/% 4) %>%
  group_by(group4) %>%
  summarise(summary = sum(C)/sum(D))`

Comment: @eipi10 this helps me get started, how can i take the output of the grouping and use mutate to replace and update the next row in place. IE.. update row 5 and 10, `%>% mutate(B=replace(B))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group5 = (1:n() - 1) %/% 5) %>% # (using eipi10's method)
  group_by(group5) %>% 
  mutate(B = ifelse(row_number() == 5, # update only 5th row of each group
                    round(100 * sum(D[1:4]) / sum(C[1:4]), 2), 
                    B)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-group5)
# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#        A     B     C     D
#    <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1      1 92.44 14261 13183
# 2      2 92.43 14244 13166
# 3      3 94.24 14730 13882
# 4      4 97.42 12149 11836
# 5      5 94.01 14431 13674
# 6      6 95.91 11038 10587
# 7      7 95.66 14886 14240
# 8      8 94.94 12587 11950
# 9      9 94.27 13251 12492
# 10    10 95.18 12789 12135
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how  to do that with `dplyr` and `roll_sumr` from `RcppRoll`. You can use `ifelse` to `mutate` the column B every 5 weeks. To so this, you can use `A %% 5` which is the modulo of column A by 5. When it is 0, you sum the previous four weeks and divide D/C as requested. `lag(roll_sumr(D,4)/roll_sumr(C,4)*100)`

```
library(dplyr);library(RcppRoll)
df%>%
  mutate(B=ifelse(A %% 5 ==0,
                  lag(roll_sumr(D,4)/roll_sumr(C,4)*100),
                  B))

    A        B     C     D
1   1 92.44000 14261 13183
2   2 92.43000 14244 13166
3   3 94.24000 14730 13882
4   4 97.42000 12149 11836
5   5 94.01091 14431 13674
6   6 95.91000 11038 10587
7   7 95.66000 14886 14240
8   8 94.94000 12587 11950
9   9 94.27000 13251 12492
10 10 95.18373 12789 12135
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="A   B        C       D
                 1   92.44   14261   13183
                 2   92.43   14244   13166
                 3   94.24   14730   13882
                 4   97.42   12149   11836
                 5   94.75   14431   13674
                 6   95.91   11038   10587
                 7   95.66   14886   14240
                 8   94.94   12587   11950
                 9   94.27   13251   12492
                 10  94.89   12789   12135",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your analytical goal is, but it seems odd to remove one of the four data rows in each group and replace it with the row of summary results for the previous group. Pending more information, here are some other options.

To create the summary by group, you could do:

```
df = df %>% mutate(group4 = (1:n() - 1) %/% 4) # Create groups of four consecutive rows

df %>% 
    group_by(group4) %>% 
    summarise(summary = sum(C)/sum(D))
```

> ```
>   group4  summary
>    <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1      0 1.063706
> 2      1 1.049375
> 3      2 1.057376
> ```

To insert the summary row, you could do the following, but then your data would not be tidy and additional analysis would be difficult:

```
df = df %>% mutate(group4 = (1:n() - 1) %/% 4) # Create groups of four consecutive rows
df = bind_rows(df,
               df %>% 
                 group_by(group4) %>% 
                 summarise(CD = sum(C)/sum(D))) %>%
  arrange(group4)
```

> ```
>     A     B     C     D group4       CD
> 1   1 92.44 14261 13183      0       NA
> 2   2 92.43 14244 13166      0       NA
> 3   3 94.24 14730 13882      0       NA
> 4   4 97.42 12149 11836      0       NA
> 5  NA    NA    NA    NA      0 1.063706
> 6   5 94.75 14431 13674      1       NA
> 7   6 95.91 11038 10587      1       NA
> 8   7 95.66 14886 14240      1       NA
> 9   8 94.94 12587 11950      1       NA
> 10 NA    NA    NA    NA      1 1.049375
> 11  9 94.27 13251 12492      2       NA
> 12 10 94.89 12789 12135      2       NA
> 13 NA    NA    NA    NA      2 1.057376
> ```

You could also add the summary for each group as a new column:

```
df = df %>% 
  mutate(group4 = (1:n() - 1) %/% 4) %>%
  group_by(group4) %>% 
  mutate(CD = sum(C)/sum(D))
```

> ```
>        A     B     C     D group4       CD
>  1     1 92.44 14261 13183      0 1.063706
>  2     2 92.43 14244 13166      0 1.063706
>  3     3 94.24 14730 13882      0 1.063706
>  4     4 97.42 12149 11836      0 1.063706
>  5     5 94.75 14431 13674      1 1.049375
>  6     6 95.91 11038 10587      1 1.049375
>  7     7 95.66 14886 14240      1 1.049375
>  8     8 94.94 12587 11950      1 1.049375
>  9     9 94.27 13251 12492      2 1.057376
> 10    10 94.89 12789 12135      2 1.057376
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Modified Scarabee's answer

```r
d %>% 
    mutate(g1 = (A - 1)%/%5, 
           g2 = A%%5 == 0) %>% 
    group_by(g1) %>% 
    mutate(V = 100 * sum(D[!g2]/sum(C[!g2]))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(B = if_else(g2, round(V, 2), B)) %>% 
    select(-g1, -g2)

#>        A     B     C     D
#>    <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1     1 92.44 14261 13183
#>  2     2 92.43 14244 13166
#>  3     3 94.24 14730 13882
#>  4     4 97.42 12149 11836
#>  5     5 94.01 14431 13674
#>  6     6 95.91 11038 10587
#>  7     7 95.66 14886 14240
#>  8     8 94.94 12587 11950
#>  9     9 94.27 13251 12492
#> 10    10 95.18 12789 12135
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked how to do this using `dplyr`, but here is another option using `data.table`.

```
dat[, grp := rep(1:(dim(dat)[1]/5), each = 5)]
dat[, B := round(c(B[1:4], 100*sum(D[1:4])/sum(C[1:4])), 2), by = grp]
dat[, .(A, B, C, D)]
```

Result:

```
     A     B     C     D
 1:  1 92.44 14261 13183
 2:  2 92.43 14244 13166
 3:  3 94.24 14730 13882
 4:  4 97.42 12149 11836
 5:  5 94.01 14431 13674
 6:  6 95.91 11038 10587
 7:  7 95.66 14886 14240
 8:  8 94.94 12587 11950
 9:  9 94.27 13251 12492
10: 10 95.18 12789 12135
```

Data generated using:

```
dat <- fread("A   B        C       D
1   92.44   14261   13183
2   92.43   14244   13166
3   94.24   14730   13882
4   97.42   12149   11836
5   94.75   14431   13674
6   95.91   11038   10587
7   95.66   14886   14240
8   94.94   12587   11950
9   94.27   13251   12492
10  94.89   12789   12135")
```